# How can i add a new component and its routing in ngx-admin-starter-kit?

Tags: angular6

I want to create a whole new web application using ngx-admin theme.
I have created a new component named "OPERATION". But, I'm not able to get the routing for it.
Need help in routing..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

first you need to import your component and you need to add your component route to the routes in the app-routing.module.ts. 
below is the routes in ngx admin app-routing.module.ts.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: NbRegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: NbLogoutComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'request-password',
        component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```